# Mac Finder dates and exif dates

Tags: macos, finder, photos

I traveled to another country and forgot to change the time of my Nikon camera to local time.
So after returning I used exiftool(`exiftool -AllDates+=1 *.*`) to change time of all the photos but in Finder, "Date Created" changes to present day.

How can I get real created date displayed in Finder?

I understand a new file is created with exiftool so Date Created is present date.

Exif data after shifting the date:

```
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:08:24 09:44:32-03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:08:24 09:48:10-03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:08:24 09:44:32-03:00   
Modify Date                     : 2018:08:19 18:46:46
Date/Time Original              : 2018:08:19 18:46:46
Create Date                     : 2018:08:19 18:46:46
```

A Get Info of an original file
[image]
The image was created at 9:04.
9:30 I was still taking pictures, not editing or something

I don't get why Apple does not have a "Date/Time Original" or "Create Date" tab in Finder

Comment: You said, "I don't get why Apple does not have a "Date/Time Original" or "Create Date" tab in Finder", well Finder in List View does have a Date Created column, you just have to right-click on the column header bar and select it. If you want to modify the dates, have a look at the man page for `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo`.

Comment: "Date Created" from Finder doesn't take the date from EXIF "Create Date". Both man pages say those commands are deprecated.

Comment: Just because a command is deprecated doesn't mean it cannot be used! If you want the file to reflect the proper Create Date in Finder then using SetFile is one way to go. I've used it more times that I can remember to get dates fixed to how I wanted them.

Comment: The Finder tells you when the actual file was created, not when the picture was taken. This is intentional, and the correct behavior. The EXIF exists for situations like this by embedding the "photo" creation date in metadata. That way no matter how many copies are created and when they are created the date the image was taken is preserved.
One tip... if you use Photos in macOS (and this applies to other photo apps as well) you can adjust the EXIF dates there. (Select image, Get Info, double click on the date). This usually won't effect the creation date in the finder.

Comment: One other note. To avoid this very problem, in the past, before database backed image apps were very popular, I would use exiftool to change the actual filenames of my images to the creation date (from the exif info). Then I could sort all my images chronologically in the Finder by name.

Comment: I'll just add that it is unusual for the modification date/time is before the creation/birth time date in the filesystem metadata.

Comment: In your OP the image under "A Get Info of an original file" the following compound command will set the Created: and Modified: times to the value of the Modified: time. Assuming the images have a .jpg extension and all the files are in the same directory, in Terminal first `cd "$dirname"` and run the following command: `for f in *.jpg; do /usr/bin/SetFile -d "$(/usr/bin/GetFileInfo -m "$f")" "$f"; done` That said, I'd make a copy of the target directory and test it on that first.

Comment: @sdmeyers What do you mean by "the correct behavior".  Why not to let the user choose which date to display? In my case it is useless to know when I created the new files (using exiftool). I would like to have displayed when the photo was taken despite there could be a difference in hours. I only use Photos for the photos taken from my iphone, no problem here, correct date is always taken.

Comment: @user3439894 I ran those commands in a duplicated directory but didn't find differences in Finder. In exif date file access changed.

Comment: Well all I can tell you is, it has always worked for me and worked in testing before I posted the command.

Comment: @dstonek  by correct behavior I mean that the Finders created date should be the date the file (or whatever) is created in the file system. This info is stored in file system metadata. You don’t want the date to suddenly represent something else. That said there alternatives to the Finder if you want some odd behavior. But from a UI/UX perspective you want that date to have one meaning everywhere.

Comment: @sdmeyers I understand. There are 3 dates to display in Finder: Date Modified, Date Created and  Date Added. It would be useful for me to also have Actual Created Date meaning EXIF's "Create Date" or "Date/Time Original".
Other thing would be to rename files using that date as suggested.
And a lot of images have Finder Date Created older than Date Modified. This is an old issue.

Comment: @dstonek I see what you are asking, and I don't entirely disagree. For example it would be nice if this information was shown in the "More info:" field in the info panel. Some metadata is shown there if it was added to to the files filesystem metadata (separate from exif data). To see what's is there you can use the `mdls filename` command. I notice that in many cases the "kMDItemContentCreationDate" has the date you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own service in automator to provide this info in a popup.

1. Create a New Service in Automator and set it so the service receives `image files` in `Finder`
2. Add a **Run Shell Script** Action. Pass input `as argument`. One-liner shell script should be (depending on your path to `exiftool`) `/usr/local/bin/exiftool -b -DateCreated $1`
3. Pass the result into a **Set Value of Variable** Action. Create a new variable (I called mine *EXIFDateCreated*
4. Add a **Get Value of Variable** and select the variable you created above. Make sure to check the `Ignore this actions input` (...the *first* time you use this action, to separate the creation of variables chain from the getting. You can repeat the above steps numerous times to add other files you want to display, but for subsequent **Get Value of Variables** you would not ignore input).
5. Add a **Run AppleScript** Action the AppleScript could be:

```
    on run {input, parameters}
        set dateCreated to first item of input as text
        display dialog "Date Created: " & dateCreated

        return input
    end run
```

Here's a screen cap of the whole Automator service...
[image]
Save the Service as something like "Show EXIF Create Date" and make sure it is activated in the Keyboard Preferences (Under the Shortcuts tab). The action should now show up when you right click/command click on an image in the finder.

Note this can be tweaked to create a pretty decent alternate Info dialog, though this just shows the basics of how it can come together.

Comment: I have a problem with the file paths: names with blanks (file not found)

Comment: Need more information. Explain in depth what your problem is.

Comment: I need to replace $1 of `/usr/local/bin/exiftool -b -DateCreated $1` by something that replace spaces between filenames by "\ ".  The pop-up display several File Not Found for each string separated by blanks in file path. `The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “File not found: `

Comment: replace `$1` with `"$*"`

Comment: Also I really think you'd be happier just using the "Photos" app or "Lightroom" if you'd rather. Both of these apps manage images beautifully and accomplish everything you are asking for.

Comment: That produced an empty output. If I '/usr/local/bin/exiftool -b -DateCreated $(echo $1 | sed "s/ /777/g")` all spaces are replaced by 777  and a single "File not found" is in the output as expected, but I don't know how to replace them by `\ `, adding a backslash before each blank space.

Comment: I don't like Photos very much. In general I don't like apps that encapsulte data in a single large file. Same as Lightroom and Time Machine.
For example, in Photos I cannot drag and drop an image to Mail or Thunderbird, I first have to d'n d to a folder and then d'n d to the email I am writing. It has some nice features (like Lightroom) like distribution map with geotagged images.

Comment: `The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “File not found: /Volumes/Seagate
File not found: 2TB/Descargas
File not found: DJI/P4P_51960.JPG”`  
This is because there is a blan between `Seagate` and `2TB` and `Descargas` and `DJI`